# Blank page after installing ISPConfig3

Tags: debian, wordpress

I have followed the instructions on [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/3/) (only step #20) and setup ISPConfig3 without problems.

The server is Debian Jessie 8.1; and it serves multiple domains. The main domain is `example.com`. with ip `xxx.aaa.xxx.aaa`. `example.com` has a WordPress website running, which loads/works with no problems.

After the installation, I go to either `example.com:8080` or `xxx.aaa.xxx.aaa:8080` and it says:

> You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.

So instead I go to either `https://example.com:8080` or `https://xxx.aaa.xxx.aaa:8080`, it warns me about the certificate, I add an exception, and the page is blank. The Page's source shows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing some packages. From [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/2/), try the following:

> apt-get install apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-doc
>   apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert
>   libapache2-mod-php5 php5 php5-common php5-gd php5-mysql php5-imap
>   phpmyadmin php5-cli php5-cgi libapache2-mod-fcgid apache2-suexec
>   php-pear php-auth php5-mcrypt mcrypt php5-imagick imagemagick libruby
>   libapache2-mod-python php5-curl php5-intl php5-memcache php5-memcached
>   php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
>   memcached libapache2-mod-passenger

```
a2enmod suexec rewrite ssl actions include dav_fs dav auth_digest cgi
```

Then restart apache server `service apache2 restart`